# Display a FrozenTime object in ISO_8601 while converted to a timezone

Tags: datetime, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a `Cake\I18n\FrozenTime` object that I need displayed both as [`2020-09-11T04:15:44+00:00`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) *and* converted to a specific timezone.

Normally, I'd call `->format('c')`, but that uses the UTC according to my app configuration.

I know I can convert to a timezone using `->i18nFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm', 'Europe/Copenhagen')`, but then I'll lose the convenience of the [`c` date format shorthand](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php#refsect1-datetime.format-parameters). [`IntlDateFormatter` predefined constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php#intl.intldateformatter-constants) are lacking, and [those from `DateTimeInterface`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php#datetime.constants.types), (specifically, `\DateTime::ATOM`) don't work.

So before I go ahead and reinvent the wheel with `->i18nFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxx", 'Europe/Copenhagen')`, is there a better way to display a `Cake\I18n\FrozenTime` in a specific [date format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php#refsect1-datetime.format-parameters) and a specific timezone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep a date object, you can simply apply the timezone conversion on the object.

`Frozen*` objects are immutable, so you'll end up with a new object when applying the conversion:

```php
echo $obj->setTimezone('Europe/Copenhagen')->format('c')
```

See also

- **[Chronos API > \Cake\Chronos\ChronosInterface::setTimezone()](https://api.cakephp.org/chronos/1.x/interface-Cake.Chronos.ChronosInterface.html#setTimezone)**